# Deny WooCommerce Checkout based on ZIP code for Choosen Payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to check against an array of zip codes IF and only IF the customer chooses the `local_pickup` option.

I have a copy of the local pickup option (local_pickup4) called `Home Delivery` and I have the array of zip codes.

The expected outcome is to get an error notice if the zip code don't match if the local pickup option has been chosen.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'zip_code_validator_for_local_home_delivery', 10, 2 );
function zip_code_validator_for_local_home_delivery( $data, $error ) {        

    $del_zones_array = array( 30030, 30032, 30033 );

    $chosen_shipping = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];

    $chosen_shipping = explode(':', $chosen_shipping);

    if ( $chosen_shipping[0] == 'local_pickup:4' && !in_array( $data['shipping_postcode'], $del_zones_array ) ) {
        $error->add( 'validation', 'We\'re sorry, but this address is outside of our online order delivery area.<br>Please contact us for assistance or choose the local pickup option.' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions to be met to display the error message: (explanation added as comment in the code)

- Local pick-up must be chosen.
- ZIPcode must NOT exist in the array of predined ZIP codes

```php
function zip_code_validator_for_local_home_delivery( $data, $error ) {        
    /* Settings */

    // Zones
    $del_zones_array = array( 30030, 30032, 30033 );

    // Shipping method
    $shipping_method = 'local_pickup:4';

    /* End settings */

    // Get chosen shipping method ID
    $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];

    // If local pickup is the chosen shipping method && ZIP code NOT in array
    if ( $chosen_shipping_method_id == $shipping_method && !in_array( $data['shipping_postcode'], $del_zones_array ) ) {
        $error->add( 'validation', 'We\'re sorry, but this address is outside of our online order delivery area.<br>Please contact us for assistance or choose the local pickup option.' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'zip_code_validator_for_local_home_delivery', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @FrancescaHulio yes, you are always close by when looking for a solution. I think that's why it's a matter of debugging. After each step you add in your code, check if the variable actually contains (the expected) value and with an if/else condition whether the if/else statement is actually executed. That is also the way I write code and eventually get the desired result. If you have 10 lines of code and something doesn't work, which line is it? If you check after each code line before continuing, you immediately know which line contains the error. Regards

Comment: So very true. I'm learning how to do that too. I use debug in wp-config and I usually google and what not, trying to find out what the notice or whatever it is, is about.

I usually get it right after some investigations and what not, but I'm not good enough yet to fix it all. Thanks again for everything.